# How to update Adobe's software unattendedly?

Tags: upgrade

I would like to use unattended-upgrade to update the Adobe Reader, Flash Player and everything else of the Canonical partners. There fore, I added in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
        "Canonical ${distro_codename}";
//  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

`sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d`

says

```
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=oneiric-security', 'o=Ubuntu,a=oneiric-updates', 'o=Canonical,a=oneiric']
Checking: acroread-common (["<Origin component:'partner' archive:'' origin:'' label:'' site:'archive.canonical.com' isTrusted:False>"])
Checking: adobe-flash-properties-gtk (["<Origin component:'partner' archive:'' origin:'' label:'' site:'archive.canonical.com' isTrusted:False>"])
Checking: adobe-flashplugin (["<Origin component:'partner' archive:'' origin:'' label:'' site:'archive.canonical.com' isTrusted:False>"])
Checking: adobereader-deu (["<Origin component:'partner' archive:'' origin:'' label:'' site:'archive.canonical.com' isTrusted:False>"])
Checking: handbrake-cli (["<Origin component:'main' archive:'oneiric' origin:'LP-PPA-stebbins-handbrake-snapshots' label:'HandBrake Snapshots' site:'ppa.launchpad.net' isTrusted:True>"])
Checking: handbrake-gtk (["<Origin component:'main' archive:'oneiric' origin:'LP-PPA-stebbins-handbrake-snapshots' label:'HandBrake Snapshots' site:'ppa.launchpad.net' isTrusted:True>"])
Checking: sopcast-player (["<Origin component:'main' archive:'oneiric' origin:'LP-PPA-ferramroberto-sopcast' label:'LffL Sopcast' site:'ppa.launchpad.net' isTrusted:True>"])
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
blacklist: []
InstCount=0 DelCount=0 BrokenCout=0
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended
```

And it won't update.
How can I update the third-party software automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for the partner repository, you need to add something like this:

```
"deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu ${distro_codename} partner"
```

The original line is this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
```

Comment: Maybe, but this gives me the same errors and empty fields. Also without "deb ".

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
"Canonical:${distro_codename}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 14.04 (trusty), and I found the clue I needed in this launchpad bug report ([897460](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/897460)).

You need to use *Origins-Pattern* in 50unattended-upgrades, in combination with either of the other answers given, which use *Allowed-Origins*. From the README:

> Origins-Pattern allows you to give a list of (glob-style) patterns to
>   match against.

My 50unattended-upgrades now looks like:

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "Canonical:${distro_codename}";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "origin=Canonical, suite=partner";
};
```

...and when I test now:

```
~# unattended-upgrade --dry-run 
/usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 9 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_1%3a20161026.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb 
/usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 11 --configure adobe-flashplugin:amd64
```

Some more resources:

- /usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md.gz
- [How to work out what Origin to use](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/03/third-party-unattended-upgrade/) (slightly old)
- [Info on adding other repositories (not just partner) to unattended upgrades](https://notatypewriter.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/things-i-learned-today-apt-cron-and-unattended-upgrades/) - also slightly old